# Why does a GIST index on a cube column in PostgreSQL actually make K-Nearest Neighbor (KNN) ORDER BY queries worse?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, cube, gist-index, nearest-neighbor

Adding a [GIST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-indexes.html) index actually seems to make K-Nearest Neighbor (KNN) `ORDER BY` queries on `cube` columns *worse* in PostgreSQL.  Why would that be, and what can be done about it?

Here's what I mean.  In a PostgreSQL database I have a table whose DDL is `create sample (id serial primary key, title text, embedding cube)` where the `embedding` column is an embedding vector of the `title` obtained with a Google language model.  The `cube` data type is provided by the cube extension, which I have installed.  Incidentally, these are titles of Wikipedia articles.  In any case, there are 1 million records.  I then perform a KNN query with the following query.  This query defines `distance` using the Euclidean distance operator `<->`, though results are similar for the other two metrics.  It does an `ORDER BY` and applies a `LIMIT` in order to find 10 Wikipedia articles with "similar" titles (the most similar being the target title itself).  That all works fine.

```sql
select sample.title, sample.embedding <-> cube('(0.18936706, -0.12455666, -0.31581765, 0.0192692, -0.07364611, 0.07851536, 0.0290586, -0.02582532, -0.03378124, -0.10564457, -0.03903799, 0.08668878, -0.15357816, -0.17793414, -0.01826405, 0.01969068, 0.11386908, 0.1555583, 0.09368557, 0.13697313, -0.05610929, -0.06536788, -0.12212707, 0.26356605, -0.06004387, -0.01966437, -0.1250324, -0.16645767, -0.13525756, 0.22482251, -0.1709727, 0.28966117, -0.07927769, -0.02498624, -0.10018375, -0.10923951, 0.04770213, 0.11573371, 0.04619929, 0.05216618, 0.19176421, 0.12948817, 0.08719034, -0.16109011, -0.02411379, -0.05638905, -0.37334979, 0.31225419, 0.0744801, 0.27044332)') distance from sample order by distance limit 10;
```

What's puzzling to me, however, is that, if I put a GIST index on the `embedding` column, the query performance actually is *worse*.  Adding the index, the query plan changes as expected, in the way expected, insofar as it uses the index.  But...it gets slower!

This seems to run contrary to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html) for `cube` which states:

> In addition, a cube GiST index can be used to find nearest neighbors using the metric operators <->, <#>, and <=> in ORDER BY clauses

They even provide an example query, which is very similar to mine.

```sql
SELECT c FROM test ORDER BY c <-> cube(array[0.5,0.5,0.5]) LIMIT 1
```

Here's the query plan and timing info *before* dropping the index.

```sql
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.41..6.30 rows=10 width=29)
   ->  Index Scan using sample_embedding_idx on sample  (cost=0.41..589360.33 rows=999996 width=29)
         Order By: (embedding <-> '(0.18936706, -0.12455666, -0.31581765, 0.0192692, -0.07364611, 0.07851536, 0.0290586, -0.02582532, -0.03378124, -0.10564457, -0.03903799, 0.08668878, -0.15357816, -0.17793414, -0.01826405, 0.01969068, 0.11386908, 0.1555583, 0.09368557, 0.13697313, -0.05610929, -0.06536788, -0.12212707, 0.26356605, -0.06004387, -0.01966437, -0.1250324, -0.16645767, -0.13525756, 0.22482251, -0.1709727, 0.28966117, -0.07927769, -0.02498624, -0.10018375, -0.10923951, 0.04770213, 0.11573371, 0.04619929, 0.05216618, 0.19176421, 0.12948817, 0.08719034, -0.16109011, -0.02411379, -0.05638905, -0.37334979, 0.31225419, 0.0744801, 0.27044332)'::cube)
(3 rows)

        title         |      distance      
----------------------+--------------------
 david petrarca       | 0.5866321762629475
 david adamski        | 0.5866321762629475
 richard ansdell      | 0.6239883862603475
 linda darke          | 0.6392124797481789
 ilias tsiliggiris    | 0.6996660649119893
 watson, jim          | 0.7059481479504834
 sk radni%c4%8dki     |   0.71718948226995
 burnham, pa          | 0.7384858030758069
 arthur (europa-park) | 0.7468462897336924
 ivan kecojevic       | 0.7488206082281348
(10 rows)

Time: 1226.457 ms (00:01.226)
```

And, here's the query plan and timing info *after* dropping the index.

```sql
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=74036.32..74037.48 rows=10 width=29)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=74036.32..171264.94 rows=833330 width=29)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=73036.29..74077.96 rows=416665 width=29)
               Sort Key: ((embedding <-> '(0.18936706, -0.12455666, -0.31581765, 0.0192692, -0.07364611, 0.07851536, 0.0290586, -0.02582532, -0.03378124, -0.10564457, -0.03903799, 0.08668878, -0.15357816, -0.17793414, -0.01826405, 0.01969068, 0.11386908, 0.1555583, 0.09368557, 0.13697313, -0.05610929, -0.06536788, -0.12212707, 0.26356605, -0.06004387, -0.01966437, -0.1250324, -0.16645767, -0.13525756, 0.22482251, -0.1709727, 0.28966117, -0.07927769, -0.02498624, -0.10018375, -0.10923951, 0.04770213, 0.11573371, 0.04619929, 0.05216618, 0.19176421, 0.12948817, 0.08719034, -0.16109011, -0.02411379, -0.05638905, -0.37334979, 0.31225419, 0.0744801, 0.27044332)'::cube))
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on sample  (cost=0.00..64032.31 rows=416665 width=29)
(6 rows)

        title         |      distance      
----------------------+--------------------
 david petrarca       | 0.5866321762629475
 david adamski        | 0.5866321762629475
 richard ansdell      | 0.6239883862603475
 linda darke          | 0.6392124797481789
 ilias tsiliggiris    | 0.6996660649119893
 watson, jim          | 0.7059481479504834
 sk radni%c4%8dki     |   0.71718948226995
 burnham, pa          | 0.7384858030758069
 arthur (europa-park) | 0.7468462897336924
 ivan kecojevic       | 0.7488206082281348
(10 rows)

Time: 381.419 ms
```

Notice:

- With Index:  1226.457 ms
- Without Index:  381.419 ms

This very puzzling behavior!  All of it is documented in a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/dventimi/pgnns) so that others can try it.  I'll add documentation about how to generate the embedding vectors, but that *shouldn't* be needed, as in the Quick-Start I show that pre-computed embedding vectors can be downloaded from my Google Drive folder.

**Addendum**

It was asked in the comments below to provide the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`.  Here that is, where

1. I re-create the (covering) index
2. I run the query with `explain (analyze, buffers)`
3. I drop the index
4. I run the query with `explain (analyze, buffers)` again

```sql
pgbench=# create index on sample using gist (embedding) include (title);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 51966.315 ms (00:51.966)
pgbench=# 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.41..4.15 rows=10 width=29) (actual time=3215.956..3216.667 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1439 read=87004 written=7789
   ->  Index Only Scan using sample_embedding_title_idx on sample  (cost=0.41..373768.39 rows=999999 width=29) (actual time=3215.932..3216.441 rows=10 loops=1)
         Order By: (embedding <-> '(0.18936706, -0.12455666, -0.31581765, 0.0192692, -0.07364611, 0.07851536, 0.0290586, -0.02582532, -0.03378124, -0.10564457, -0.03903799, 0.08668878, -0.15357816, -0.17793414, -0.01826405, 0.01969068, 0.11386908, 0.1555583, 0.09368557, 0.13697313, -0.05610929, -0.06536788, -0.12212707, 0.26356605, -0.06004387, -0.01966437, -0.1250324, -0.16645767, -0.13525756, 0.22482251, -0.1709727, 0.28966117, -0.07927769, -0.02498624, -0.10018375, -0.10923951, 0.04770213, 0.11573371, 0.04619929, 0.05216618, 0.19176421, 0.12948817, 0.08719034, -0.16109011, -0.02411379, -0.05638905, -0.37334979, 0.31225419, 0.0744801, 0.27044332)'::cube)
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=1439 read=87004 written=7789
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=14 read=6 dirtied=2
 Planning Time: 0.432 ms
 Execution Time: 3316.266 ms
(10 rows)

Time: 3318.333 ms (00:03.318)
pgbench=# drop index sample_embedding_title_idx;
DROP INDEX
Time: 182.324 ms
pgbench=# 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=74036.35..74037.52 rows=10 width=29) (actual time=6052.845..6057.210 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=70 read=58830
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=74036.35..171265.21 rows=833332 width=29) (actual time=6052.825..6057.021 rows=10 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=70 read=58830
         ->  Sort  (cost=73036.33..74077.99 rows=416666 width=29) (actual time=6002.928..6003.019 rows=8 loops=3)
               Sort Key: ((embedding <-> '(0.18936706, -0.12455666, -0.31581765, 0.0192692, -0.07364611, 0.07851536, 0.0290586, -0.02582532, -0.03378124, -0.10564457, -0.03903799, 0.08668878, -0.15357816, -0.17793414, -0.01826405, 0.01969068, 0.11386908, 0.1555583, 0.09368557, 0.13697313, -0.05610929, -0.06536788, -0.12212707, 0.26356605, -0.06004387, -0.01966437, -0.1250324, -0.16645767, -0.13525756, 0.22482251, -0.1709727, 0.28966117, -0.07927769, -0.02498624, -0.10018375, -0.10923951, 0.04770213, 0.11573371, 0.04619929, 0.05216618, 0.19176421, 0.12948817, 0.08719034, -0.16109011, -0.02411379, -0.05638905, -0.37334979, 0.31225419, 0.0744801, 0.27044332)'::cube))
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               Buffers: shared hit=70 read=58830
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on sample  (cost=0.00..64032.33 rows=416666 width=29) (actual time=0.024..3090.103 rows=333333 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared read=58824
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=3 read=3 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 0.129 ms
 Execution Time: 6057.388 ms
(18 rows)

Time: 6053.284 ms (00:06.053)
```